# Scriptural reference for the statement "gods reside towards our right side"?

Tags: scripture, gods

Quoting from an article hosted at kamakoti.org ["VEDA DHARMA SASTRA PARIPALANA SABHA (Regd.), Kumbhakonam, Publication No. 50"](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/articles/Veda%20Dharma%20Shastra%20Paripalana%20Sabha%20Morning%20Routine.html):

> *MORNING ROUTINE*

> Everyone should get up from bed in Braahma muhurtham,i.e. five nazhigas (two hours) before sunrise, i.e. 4 a.m. If we sleep beyond
> that time, we will not only lose the merit we have, but also attract
> the curse of Pitrus.
> During Sandhya times, taking food, enjoying sex, sleep, reading- these four are prohibited. As soon as we get up from bed, we should
> see auspicious objects while waking up. We should contemplate on God,
> Rishis and Punyatmas (holy persons). We should then go to a deserted
> place at least 100 feet away in east, south or north direction, keep
> water and soil, conceal head with cloth, face north in daytime or
> south in night time and pass stools silently. Passing stools and urine
> should not be done in front of Agni, woman, brahmana, Guru and cow and
> in water, ditches of animals, peaks of hills, temple premises, banks
> of river, under a tree, areas of fodgrains and facing temple. If urine
> and stools come into contact with any part of the body, that part
> should be cleaned with soil. Cleaning should be done first for stools,
> then urine, followed by left hand, both hands and feet. After cleaning
> thus, brushing teeth should be done. Brushing of teeth should not be
> done with soil, stone or ash; it may be done using tooth powder not
> mixed with lime and tooth stick of banyan or neem; it should not be
> done with index finger. But brushing teeth should not be done on days
> of Parva (Amavasya/ Purnima) and Sankramana with sticks. All these
> instructions can be very easily observed, but we fail owing to
> laziness, negligence and insincerity; there is nothing impossible
> about it. If we analyse the instructions in the Sastras, we find that
> they are meant for our good and health free from disease. Hence we
> should follow the instructions in Sastras as far as possible. Formerly
> nobody used to dirty the waters. Now all sit in water, clean
> themselves after stools/ urine, brush their teeth there itself and
> spit and rinse their mouths and thus dirty the waters.

> *Daily Routine*
>
> There are three types of benefits for the instructions given in our
> Sastras. One is, benefit experienced here and now; the second, to be
> experienced in the next birth; the third, benefit in both ways. This
> is also called Drishta phala (seen benefit); Adrishta phala (unseen
> benefit); Drishtaadrishta phala (Seen and unseen benefit). Forgetting
> the Unseen benefit of purifying (after stools/ urine), the seen
> benefit is experienced by all who follow. It is saddening that many of
> us follow the practices from cold countries without bothering about
> their applicability. It is the Apaana air that expels stools. At that
> time, bad smell is seen in the place. Is it not necessary to wash with
> soil and water to rid of the bad smell? In what way is one, who does
> not wash after passing urine, is superior to animals? By washing feet
> frequently, the heat in the head reduces. By rinsing, the disease in
> teeth goes away.
>
> *Rinsing, Aachamanam and cleaning of teeth*
>
> After cleaning private parts with soil and water, one should tie the
> dhoti ‘kachcham’ properly, if loosened, tie the hair and rinse the
> mouth. Spitting the water should be done on the bank of river and that
> place should also be washed with water. **While rinsing, one should
> sit and spit on the left side, as right side is of Devas**. Rinsing of
> mouth has been specified to be four times after passing urine and
> 16-18 times after passing of stools.

My question is about the bold portion. Which scripture states that on our right side always reside the Devas? Also what about the left side? Which beings reside on that side?

Comment: For fun part -  To me it looks like condemnation of Asuras. :-D

Comment: You mean the left side belongs to asuras? @SwiftPushkar

Comment: @Rickross- Most probably , because other side should be opposite.  One Other theory is right side belongs to Purusha and left to prakriti etc. but in that case spiting on side of prakriti doesn't fit correctly. In shakta tantric paths of spiritual practices Dakshinachara (right path) and the Vamachara methods are followed. But I don't know much about that. And It could be related to that also.

Comment: Okay @SwiftPushkar btw just like Devas and Asuras are opposite, Devas and Pitrus are also opposite in a sense but spitting on the Pitrus side is also not acceptable so let's wait for an answer.